# how to push tableview to UIView dynamically in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

> i am displaying list content in table view  now i want when i click
>   one menu of list that menu content display in `UIView` on next screen 
>   . how to push `UITableView` to `UIView` dynamically in `iOS`.

```
      #import "SmsCategoryTitleTableViewController.h"
    #import "CategoryMainWindowViewController.h"
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
    #import "FMDatabase.h"
    #import "FMResultSet.h"
   #import "SmsTitle.h"
   #import "SMSCategory.h"
   #import"smsDisplayViewController.h"

   @interface SmsCategoryTitleTableViewController ()

  @end

     @implementation SmsCategoryTitleTableViewController
     @synthesize theSearchBar,Id;
    @synthesize theTableView;
   @synthesize array;
   @synthesize disableViewOverlay;
   @synthesize Arrayobject;

 - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self SearchBarCode];
  [self GetTableData];

  [self.tableView reloadData];
  filteredContentList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
  // [self performSelector:@selector(push:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2f];
   }


   - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
   {
  self = [super initWithStyle:style];
  if (self) {
  }
  return self;
  }


    -(void)GetTableData
  {
  array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentDir = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
  self.databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SMS.sqlite"];

 FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:self.databasePath];
[database setLogsErrors:TRUE];
[database open];



    NSString *anQuery = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM SMSnJokes 
    where CategoryId=%@",self.Id];

  FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:anQuery];

    while([results next])
     {
    SmsTitle *title=[[SmsTitle alloc]init];
    title.Id = [results stringForColumn:@"Id"];
    title.CategoryId = [results stringForColumn:@"CategoryId"];
    title.Title = [results stringForColumn:@"Title"];
    [array addObject:title];
  //  NSLog(@"SMS LIST %@",title.Title);

   }


    [database close];

 }


    -(void)SearchBarCode
 {
   self.disableViewOverlay = [[UIView  
   alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,44.0f,320.0f,0)];
  self.disableViewOverlay.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
   self.disableViewOverlay.alpha = 0;

  theSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 374.0f, 50)];
   theSearchBar.delegate =self;
  [self.tableView addSubview:theSearchBar];
  self.navigationItem.title=@"SMS LIST";

  [[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:theSearchBar];

 }

   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

 // Return the number of sections.
 return 1;
  }

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
   (NSInteger)section {
  // Return the number of rows in the section.
  if (isSearching)
  {
    return [filteredContentList count];
  }
  else
  {
    return [array count];
  }

  }




     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
      static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
     UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView 
      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];

    if(!cell)
    {


      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
   }

   if (isSearching)
   {
    cell.textLabel.text = [filteredContentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  }
  else
  {
      SmsTitle *title = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     [cell.textLabel  setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",[title    
  valueForKey:@"Title"]]];
  }
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

     return cell;

  }
  - (void)searchTableList
  {
    NSString *searchString =theSearchBar.text;
   filteredContentList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  [filteredContentList   removeAllObjects];
   for (SmsTitle *title in array)
   {
    NSString *tempStr = title.Title;
            NSComparisonResult result = [tempStr compare:searchString options:    
     (NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, 
    [searchString   length])];
    if (result == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        [filteredContentList addObject:title.Title];
    }
    }


   }




   #pragma mark - Search Implementation


  - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  [self.theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
   }


   - (void) dismissKeyboard
   {
    [self.theSearchBar becomeFirstResponder];
    }


    - (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
  {

    isSearching = YES;

    [theSearchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];


    }

  - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
  {
   NSLog(@"Text change - %d",isSearching);

  //Remove all objects first.
  [filteredContentList removeAllObjects];


   if([searchText length] != 0) {
    isSearching = YES;
    [self searchTableList];

   }
    else {
    isSearching = NO;

    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
   }

 - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
    {
   theSearchBar.text=nil;
  [theSearchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
  [theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }

  - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
   {
  [theSearchBar setShowsCancelButton: YES animated: YES];





[self searchTableList];
 [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

}

```
  - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar activate:(BOOL) active
  {
  self.theTableView.allowsSelection = !active;
  self.theTableView.scrollEnabled = !active;

  if (!active)
  {

    [disableViewOverlay removeFromSuperview];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
  }
  else
  {
    self.disableViewOverlay.alpha = 0;
    [self.view addSubview:self.disableViewOverlay];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"FadeIn" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    self.disableViewOverlay.alpha = 0.6;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    NSIndexPath *selected = [self.theTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if (selected)
    {
        [self.theTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selected
                                         animated:NO];
    }
    }
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:active animated:YES];
    }


   -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self.theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
   }
    -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    {
      textField.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDefault ;
      return[textField resignFirstResponder];
     }


  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
  *)indexPath
   {
  smsDisplayViewController *viewController1 = [[smsDisplayViewController alloc] 
  init];

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController1 animated:YES];

   }
```

Comment: I think you want to pass data of selected cell in table view to another view on next screen.

Comment: means not getting you

Comment: i am using storyboard not using nib this tutorial for nib file

Comment: Here: http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Comment: its also not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ok got your point. I think you want to pass data of selected cell to
>   next UIViewController. Assume, you want to pass cell title label and
>   you have an array of objects.    In your`smsDisplayViewController.h`

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    @interface smsDisplayViewController : UIViewController 
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *cellName;
```

Now in your `SmsCategoryTitleTableViewController.m` you have
 `NSMutableArray *nameList;`
Then in your table view delegate method

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
         {
             [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

             smsDisplayViewController *viewController1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginIdentifier"]; 

             viewController1.cellName=[nameList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

               [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController1 animated:YES];
         }
```

**UPDATE** This is the code you posted first in your question.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
               [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
                 smsDisplayViewController *viewController1 = [[smsDisplayViewController 
                 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewController1" bundle:nil];
               [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController1 animated:YES];
}
```

> Now the wrong thing you are doing here
>   is`initWithNibName:@"viewController1"`. If you are not using any nib
>   file then your code should be

```
smsDisplayViewController *viewController1 = [[smsDisplayViewController alloc] init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController1 animated:YES];
```

---

Comment: what is that login identifier

Comment: @ChetanGharat,It is your segue identifier that you have to set with your view controller in storyboard.When you create link of viewController with navigation controller,click on that link to add segueIdentifier. Try and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: actualy ia m not adding any view controller doing dynamically adding class and coding for that so it not useful for me

Comment: how push without using storyboard and nib file adding only class and move table view to view controller

Comment: @ChetanGharat,You mean to say,you are creating `UITableView` and `UIView` programmatically right?

Comment: Ok,See the updated code. try removing initWithNib.Just use init. Hope it works. If you don't have any nib file then it must be only `init`. You cannot pass object of viewController as nib name.Nib name is the name of your xib file.Don't use any preparefosegue method.Just user `didSelect` method and it will work fine

Comment: Show me snippet of your code you are using in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. and also tell me the error you are getting while tapping on cell.

Comment: there is no error i posted my all code in my Question

Comment: when i tapping on cell there is not happen any action

Comment: @ChetanGharat, Finally... Happy to help you.

Comment: ya thank but its not show any data am creating three buttons and one uitextview but its not show

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Accessory Buttons** in UITableView or learn more about **segues**.

Comment: I have an array of contents on the TableView I need to tap inside the content and get the ViewController as result.

Comment: yes i am using that buttons but how to move dynamically

Comment: I am not getting you. What do you mean about move **dynamically**? Show me your code and what have you tried.

Comment: i use that method but not moving

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `prepareForSegue:` to pass data to another ViewController.
You can learn it from [Here](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/) which teaches you how to transfer data between ViewControllers while using Segue.